# module controller with initiation parameter

Tags: mithril.js

When using `m.module`, I often would like to provide arguments to the controller constructor so that the first rendering starts with the right data. However, the Mithril documentation and examples always show `module.controller()` and `module.vm.init()` without parameters.

To go around this issue and have `module.controller(initData)` I've resorted to use this small utility function to wrap and extend the existing m.Module:

```
var mModule = function (dom, mod, arg) {
  return m.module(dom, {
    view: mod.view,
    controller: mod.controller.bind(mod.controller,arg)
  });
};
```

Questions:

1. Is this an anti-pattern? Is there an alternate recommended way instantiate the module with custom external data?
2. Would this cause issues with m.route? I saw some mentions of recursive calls in the source code but could not get my head around it.
3. Following the 2 points above, is the lack of parameter for `m.module` a deliberate design choice?

Oh...and thanks to all involved for the existing documentation and discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not an anti-pattern, and it's an idea that is [explored in one of the blog articles](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril-blog/just-what-the-doctor-prescribed.html), and also by [Moria](https://github.com/gitter-badger/moria) (a router extension library for Mithril)

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for the follow-up.